# Actions on Google: Mixing Smarthome action and conversational action

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible to mix a Smarthome action and a conversational action so that user have only to peform one account linking operation?

Answer (score 0):

A smart home action must be a separate project from your conversational action. This means you will need to have each separately link their accounts. Although you can link them to a single backend, they will need to be implemented orthogonally.